# Why do I see different values for a gauge in different timeframes?

Tags: metrics, gauge, datadog

I have a gauge in datadog and want to see the 'last' value.

But when I select `the last day` in the dashboard time-picker I see a different value than when I select `the last week`. My natural understanding is that 'last' gauge value should be the same regardless of how far back in time I go.

Am I missing some understanding of how gauges or datadog works?

[image]